# Inserting file input element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, file-io

I'm having trouble inserting file input elements with jQuery. What I want to happen is when a user selects a file using the input element, jQuery should hide that input and insert a new file input in its place.

Here's my relevant markup:

```
<div id="select_images">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" />
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
$('#select_images input').change(function(){
    // User selected some images to upload, hide this file input
    $(this).css('right', '-10000px');

    // Insert a new file input to take its place
    $('#select_images').append('<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" />');
});
```

It kind of works. When I select a file using the file input already on the page, jQuery hides it and inserts a new one. When I try to do the same again however, jQuery does not insert a new file input.

I can't see any reason that the above code will only insert one additional file input, so I'm pretty stumped. I've confirmed this behaviour using both Firebug and POSTing the form data to my backend script.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I guess my question is why do this?  Knowing that might help with the solution...

Comment: Because I would like multiple file uploads from different directories without using something like Uploadify or SWFUpload. Using the `multiple=""` attribute only lets you add multiple files from the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using live

```
$('#select_images input').live('change',function(){...
```

when you dynamically add the elements to the DOM the event handlers do not automatically get attached to them, to attach the event handlers to the dynamically added elements you can use `.live` or `.delegate`

*example with delegate*

```
$("#select_images").delegate('input','change',function(){
//handler code here

});
```

[**`.live`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[**`.delegate`**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

[**When You Should Use jQuery’s Live and Delegate Methods**](http://shaneriley.tumblr.com/post/1679999567/when-you-should-use-jquerys-live-and-delegate-methods)

Comment: Works, thanks. Out of interest, why does this method work and the .change() method doesn't? Is the .change() method only allowed to fire once?

Comment: `.change()` is short-hand for: `.bind('change', function () {})` which only affects objects already in the DOM, when you dynamically add a new file input the `.bind()` will not affect it. Using `.live()` will affect the dom "now and in the future" as the documentation states. http://api.jquery.com/live/ . I would recommend using `.delegate()` however (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). $('#select_images').delegate('input', 'change', function () {});

Answer (score 0):

The new input that you have added doesn't have any `onchange` event handler. If you put the event handler in a named function, you can easily bind it to the new input that you create:

```
function handleChange(){
  // User selected some images to upload, hide this file input
  $(this).css('right', '-10000px');

  // Insert a new file input to take its place
  $('#select_images').append(
    $('<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" />').change(handleChange)
  );
}

$('#select_images input').change(handleChange);
```